# getting file name from file

Tags: actionscript-3

I have the following code:

```
private function uploadFile(file:File, packageId:String):void {
            try {
                var fullpath:String = file.nativePath;
                var filename:String = fullpath.substr(fullpath.lastIndexOf("/")+1,fullpath.length);
                packageItem.status = "Uploading file: "+filename;
                file.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, function(event:ProgressEvent):void{uploadProgress(event, packageId)} );
                file.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.COMPLETE, function(event:flash.events.Event):void{uploadComplete(event, packageId)} );
                file.upload(urlRequest, packageId);
            } catch (error:Error) {
                logging.log(error.message); 
            }
        }
```

So i extract the filename from the path in a file object.

the files are comming from:

```
File.applicationStorageDirectory
```

The problem is that this isnt working for windows because they are using backslashes instead of slashes like mac osx does. What would be the best way to seperate the filename and file so it works on mac and windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its fairly obvious.

The `url` property has the filesystem url of the file. So a file with a `nativePath` of

> C:\Documents and Settings\some_file.txt

would have a `url` of

> file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/some_file.txt

Now you just need to split on **`/`** and you're done.

P.S.: You might have to [`unescape`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118ccf9c47f-7ff0.html) the file name to remove the url-type formatting